# Laser and resistor

Tags: voltage, laser

I have a blue-violet 5mW laser that needs 3.3V. I am thinking of powering it using a 5V source and having a resistor connected in series. I measured the current when connected to 3.3V and it was 180mA. So a 10 Ohm should be fine. Am I missing anything?

Yiannis

Comment: Would your resistor withstand around 350 mW? Better use two diodes in series as a simple solution.  This way the voltage drop won't depend on the current.

Comment: Also, be aware that you're dissipating around 300mW there (whether you do it with diodes or resistors), so you'll need parts rated at that power. For reference, a "standard" through-hole resistor is generally rated at 250mW - and most surface mount components less.

Comment: @stefandz Added the point about power to my comment as well before your comment was posted. Sorry about that :)

Comment: No dramas. I have a question coming up if you wanna play!

Comment: I will use PWM to drive the laser. The laser will fade in-out in a 5sec period, so I think even a standard 1/4W resistor should be fine.

Comment: @yiannisk Then you might even not need the resistor or whatever. Just don't drive it with 100%.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's a very bad idea. You have to be very careful with PWM. If you apply the full 5 volts without a limiting resistor, the laser can fail in microseconds.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I agree. It came to emphasize the bad idea in the OPs comment :) The better idea was in the first comment.

Comment: Can you post the diode's data sheet or a link to it, please?

Answer (score 1):

180 milliamperes sounds quite high for a 5 milliwatt diode, so I believe what you're missing is that the forward voltage drop across the diode (Vf) is specified with a certain current through the diode, not the other way around.

What that means is you need to look at the data sheet to determine the proper current at which to drive the diode so that it'll drop 3.3 volts, and then if you want to use a 5 volt supply to drive the diode, calculate the resistance required to drop the difference between the supply voltage and Vf, like this:

$$ Rs = \frac{Vs - Vf}{If} $$

where Rs is the ballast resistor, Vs is the supply voltage, Vf is the diode's forward voltage at If, and If is the diode's rated forward current.

Comment: The laser is taken from this laser pointer http://www.aliexpress.com/item/MILITARY-5MW-Blue-Laser-Pointer-Professional-Lazer-Blue-Violet-Laser-Pointer-Pen-Beam-Light-High-Quality/32390969269.html so I don't have the data sheet. I guess the current is high because is blue violet laser and not a red. I just contacted seller for more info.